# Monit & Rails sunspot_solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, solr, monit

I've setup monit to monitor my sunspot_solr process, which seems to work at first.  If I restart the monit service with `sudo service monit restart` my sunspot process starts:

```
 ps aux | grep sunspot
```

```html
root      4086  0.0  0.0   9940  1820 ?        Ss   12:41   0:00 bash ./solr start -f -s /ebs/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.4/solr/solr
root      4137 45.1  4.8 1480560 185632 ?      Sl   12:41   0:09 java -server -Xss256k -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=1 -XX:CMSTriggerPermRatio=80 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/ebs/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.4/solr/server/logs/solr_gc.log -Djetty.port=8983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djetty.home=/ebs/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.4/solr/server -Dsolr.solr.home=/ebs/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.4/solr/solr -Dsolr.install.dir=/ebs/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.4/solr -jar start.jar --module=http
ubuntu    4192  0.0  0.0  10460   936 pts/3    S+   12:41   0:00 grep --color=auto sunspot
```

However, I'm also running `tail -f /var/logs/monit.log` and see this at the same time:

```html
[CST Mar  3 12:42:54] error    : 'sunspot_solr' process is not running
[CST Mar  3 12:42:54] info     : 'sunspot_solr' trying to restart
[CST Mar  3 12:42:54] info     : 'sunspot_solr' start: /usr/bin/sudo
[CST Mar  3 12:43:25] error    : 'sunspot_solr' failed to start
```

Plus, to make sure monit can actually restart the sunspot_solr process, I run `sudo kill -9 <the pid>` and monit can't restart sunspot_solr:

```html
[CST Mar  3 12:44:25] error    : 'sunspot_solr' process is not running
[CST Mar  3 12:44:25] info     : 'sunspot_solr' trying to restart
[CST Mar  3 12:44:25] info     : 'sunspot_solr' start: /usr/bin/sudo
[CST Mar  3 12:44:55] error    : 'sunspot_solr' failed to start
```

Obviously something is wrong with my `monit-solr_sunspot.conf` file, but after messing around with it for a few hours now, I'm stumped:

```html
check process sunspot_solr with pidfile /ebs/staging/shared/pids/sunspot-solr.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/sudo -H -u root /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /ebs/staging/releases/20160226191542; bundle exec sunspot-solr start -- -p 8983 -d /ebs/staging/shared/solr/data --pid-dir=/ebs/staging/shared/pids'"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/sudo -H -u root /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /ebs/staging/releases/20160226191542; bundle exec sunspot-solr stop -- -p 8983 -d /ebs/staging/shared/solr/data --pid-dir=/ebs/staging/shared/pids'"
```

I've adapted this monit script to suit my needs: [Sample sunspot-solr.monit](https://gist.github.com/pcolazurdo/4532625) but am still having no luck!

**UPDATE**
I've gotten monit to successfully restart sunspot_solr if I kill it, however it still produces the error that it failed to restart in the `monit.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think `monit` runs as root. You may not want to use `sudo` both because it prompts for a password and because monit doesn't need it.